# How can i do it in single SQL?

Tags: sql

I have this Table like this

```
ID | NAME     | AGE | ADDRESS   | SALARY
```

and an ID (2)

```
AGE of ID 2 is 25,
```

Now i need to count total number of record with AGE 25. How can i do it in single SQL Query? is there any why?

i currently doing it in 2 query. in one i return AGE with ID.

```
select AGE from table_name where ID = 2
```

it return AGE 25

and 2nd query i count number of record with this AGE.

```
select COUNT(*) from table_name where age =25
```

i want to do it in one SQL Query. is there any way ?

Comment: Please tag your DBMS.

Comment: Please show us what you tried.

Comment: i currently doing it in 2 query. in one i return AGE with ID. and 2nd query i count number of record with this AGE.

Comment: Feel free to add those two queries to your question by editing it, such that others understand your problem

Comment: It's been a long time since I've used SQL but have you tried something like select count(id) from tablename where age = 25?

Comment: i did not have my age at 1st. i have a id, with it i need to found out age 1st, than in 2nd query i count total record with that age. i want to do this in 1 SQL query.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Answer (score 0):

use SQL COUNT function

```
select COUNT(*) from mytable where age =25
```

Comment: i am doing it already. i don't have age i have id. in 1 query i get age from id. than in 2nd query i get count form age, by this query. i want to do it in 1 query. is there any way can do it?

Answer (score 0):

You want to count the number of rows with the same age as the specified ID?

You can use a *windowed count*

```
select Agecount
from (
    select *, Count(*) over (partition by Age) Agecount
    from YourTable
)t
where id=?
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Group by` with subquery

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS ageCount
FROM table_name
WHERE age in (SELECT age FROM table_name WHERE ID = 2)
GROUP BY age
```

Comment: i am doing it already. i don't have age i have id.  in 1 query i get age from id. than in 2nd query i get count form age, by this query. i want to do it in 1 query. is there any way can do it?

Comment: I corrected the answer. It now produces the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

For Questions like this the best way is use multiple conditions using Where keyword with And-Or Operators.
This query should work for your requirement without complicating anything.

```
select count(*) from table_name where ID=2 and age=25;
```

Comment: I don't have age, i have only id